# Singularity container with stringr fails only locally with 'libicui18n.so.66: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'

Tags: r, stringr, icu, singularity-container

I enjoy using the Singularity container software, as well as the R package 'stringr' to work with strings.

What I fail to understand is why a Singularity container fails locally (i.e. on my Ubuntu 20.04 computer), yet passes remotely (i.e. on GitHub Actions), when both containers are built at approximately the same time.

Here I run a simple script ([1], see below) that uses `stringr`:

```
singularity run --bind $PWD/scripts/ stringr.sif scripts/demo_container.R
```

(I can remove `--bind $PWD/scripts/`, but I want to have exactly the same call here as on GitHub Actions)

The error I get is:

```
'stringr.sif' running with arguments 'scripts/demo_container.R'
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stringr’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/richel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  libicui18n.so.66: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Execution halted
```

On GitHub Actions, however, this exact call passes without problems (from [this GitHub Actions log](https://github.com/richelbilderbeek/stringr_singularity/runs/5318541678?check_suite_focus=true)):

```
'stringr.sif' running with arguments 'scripts/demo_container.R'
Hello world
```

The Singularity script is very simple, it only installs and updates `apt`, then installs the `stringr` package ([2], see below).

I understand that this is a shared objects problem, there are some workaround that fail in this context:

- `sudo apt install libicu-dev`: ICU is the library that `stringr` uses
- uninstall `stringr` and install it again, forcing a recompilation of the shared object, from [this GitHub Issue comment](https://github.com/tidyverse/stringr/issues/320#issuecomment-560991587)

How can it be my Singularity container fails locally, yet passes on GitHub Actions? How can I fix this, so that the container works in both environments?

A non-fix is to use `rocker/tidyverse` as a base, which [I can get to work successfully](https://github.com/richelbilderbeek/tidyverse_singularity), as the question is more about why this `stringr` setup fails.

Thanks and cheers, Richel Bilderbeek

### [1] [demo_container.R](https://github.com/richelbilderbeek/stringr_singularity/blob/master/scripts/demo_container.R)

```
library(stringr)
message(stringr::str_trim("   Hello world   "))
```

### [2] [Singularity](https://github.com/richelbilderbeek/stringr_singularity/blob/master/Singularity)

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: r-base

%post
    sed -i 's/$/ universe/' /etc/apt/sources.list
    apt-get update
    apt-get clean
    Rscript -e 'install.packages("stringr")'

%runscript
echo "'stringr.sif' running with arguments '$@'"
Rscript "$@"
```

Comment: You bootsrap your container based on r-base, without using a specific version tag. You may have just a different container locally. You can check this with bash command `diff local.sig remote.sig`. Is there a reason against just using docker image `rocker/tidyverse` instead?

Comment: Hi @danlooo, thanks for the help. I build the container locally and remotely at approximately the same time, so I guess they are the same? The reason I do not use `rocker/tidyverse` here is to have a minimal reprex of the bug that plagues me for months.

Comment: Do the diff by comparing the checksums of the file. Guessing is not reliable.

Comment: Hi @danlooo, I just compared the checksums, they indeed do differ. But the reason they differ is -of course- unknown. However, when I run `sessionInfo` and `installed.packages` I get exactly the same results. Is there something you recommend me to check?

Answer (score 1):

I had what seems like the same problem, and setting the environment variable `R_LIBS` solved it. Details below.

As background, the typical error message would look something like this:

```bash
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/mrodo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/fs/libs/fs.so':
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /home/mrodo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/fs/libs/fs.so)
```

The reason, as I understand it, is that the R package `fs` had been installed previously to the library that the container is using, but using a different system (either the host system or a container based on a different image). This installation of `fs` is incompatible with the running container and so throws an error. In this case the error is because a different version of GLIBC is available then what `fs` wants to use.

How this scenario arose is as follows. Upon trying to install a package using R inside a previous container based off a different image but also running `R4.2.x`, no default library was writeable as `R_LIBS_USER` was not set and/or did not exist (if it does not exist when R is loaded, then it is not added to the library paths). Then R prompted to install to a personal library, and I accepted this. But my latest container prompted to use the same personal library, creating the clash.

The solution I used was to set a directory in my home directory as the first path returned by `.libPaths()`. To do this, you create the directory (won't work if it doesn't exist first0 and add its path as the first path of `R_LIBS`. You can do that in various ways, but I used the `--env` option for `singularity run`.

To make it easier to set this every time, I created an alias for the `run` command, adding the following to `.bashrc`:

```
export R_LIBS_USER_AR42=~/.R/ar42
mkdir -p "$R_LIBS_USER_AR42"
alias ar42='singularity run --env "R_LIBS='$R_LIBS_USER_AR42':/usr/local/lib/R/site-library:/usr/local/lib/R/library$sif/ar42.sif radian'
```

That would just be tweaked for your own settings.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue has to do with the fact that Singularity binds your home directory by default (I currently use v3.9.0). If your container contains version "A" of an R package but on your host system you have version "B" and the dependencies for version "A" and version "B" clash, you will get this error.

Adding the `--no-home` argument solved the issue for me:

`singularity run --no-home --bind $PWD/scripts/ stringr.sif scripts/demo_container.R`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error message, you'll see that the library that cannot be loaded is in your HOME on the host OS: `/home/richel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/stringi/libs/stringi.so`

This suggests that the R being used is one you have locally installed on the host and not the one installed in the image. Since singularity processes inherit the full host environment by default, I'd guess you've modified your `$PATH` and that's clobbering the value set inside the container. Since the environment on the CI / actions server is clean, it is able to run successfully.

I strongly recommend always using the [`-e`/`--cleanenv`](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.9/user-guide/environment_and_metadata.html?highlight=cleanenv#environment-from-the-host) parameters to ensure that the environment inside the singularity container is the same anywhere it is run.

Comment: Hi @tsnowlan, thanks for the helpful insight! I have not modified `$PATH` myself, nor do so in the Singularity script. When running the container like you recommended (i.e. `singularity run --cleanenv --bind $PWD/scripts/ stringr.sif scripts/demo_container.R`) the error remains exactly the same. I tried building with you recommended flag, which fails. But I deduce from your reasoning that the version of `stringr` I installed locally differs from the one installed in the container. Installing these packages again locally does not appear to fix it :-/ ?